# Random trial with questionnaire and multiple answer/outcome: Should the p-value be adjusted?

Tags: p-value, multiple-comparisons, survey, bonferroni

I have randomly allocated person into two groups, a control and intervention group. Each of the person I ask 8 questions (=hypothesis). At the end I want to compare if there is a difference between the groups answering question. Should I adjust the p-value (Bonferroni etc.) or can I use the unadjusted p-value since?

I am confused since I don't ask the same hypothesis to more than two groups, but I test 8 hypothesis to two groups.